# define a line as a subpart of a closed path in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have a path extracted from a bitmap. I would like to extract a line from the contour of this shape.
To so do I select the corresponding nodes, and copy/paste them to make a new path.
The result I get is a closed line.
The first picture shows the original shape, and the second the result I get.

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to remove the vertical line linking the node on top to the bottom one.

How may I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking on many buttons, I managed to find the solution, which was trivial!
We just have to select the two nodes linked, then click en the button "Delete a segment between two non terminal nodes"

*(nb: as Insckape is installed in French on my computer, I'm not sure of the exact name of the button !)*

[image]